# mbed TLS - porting to NON-OS (no thread context)

Tags: ssl, mbed

In porting mbedtls to an OS without threading context (but with TCP/IP), do you need a thread context (such as blocking I/O - with or without timeout)?

My OS does not provide a thread context. I can create network endpoints, and am notified (via call-back) when data becomes available.

I noticed that the initial SSL negotiation required the ability to read/write SSL records in a synchronous fashion.

I saw that the client programs drove the SSL engine in a loop (`WANT_READ`/`WANT_WRITE`). Is this type of polling sufficient to drive the SSL engine?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need threads for mbed TLS. The SSL engine only requires the read/write calls to function (after set-up of the connection of course), but both blocking and non-blocking options are available.